# How to detect repeated word or message in a string using python

Tags: python

I want to detect the Repeating word or Repeating Sentence , SPAM messages in the Python. For example

1. - nope nope nope nope
2. Ghosts Rider \nBeautiful beautiful beautiful Beautiful beautiful beautiful \nCome Cops Cops Cops Cops Cops Cops Cops Cops Cops
3. Movie cancel movie cancel music cancel even shut down and being shut down with it will it be shut down shut down a video chat down

The idea is to protect system from these sort of spam message. Is there any open library available for this problem, or we need to build some custom logic to handle it.

Any idea for the best practice , would be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Library recommendation requests are specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow. The problem of finding repeated substrings is not hard to solve with regular expressions.